On compact embedding between Sobolev space on Torus
Proposition For all $\sigma>0,\, s\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
j\colon H^{s+\sigma}(\mathbb{T}^n)\to H^{s}(\mathbb{T}^n)
\end{align}
is compact. Here $j$  denotes the natural injection.
(This proposition is a particular case of proposition 3.4 in PDE Taylor)
Reference: M.E. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations. 1: Basic Theory, Corr. 2. print (Springer, New York Heidelberg, 1997).
Question: Is there an analogously result in $L^p(\mathbb{T}^n)$, $1<p<\infty$?, i.e, Is $j\colon H^{s+\sigma,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)\to H^{s,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)$ also compact? Thanks.
Actualization: I just found that the embedding $H^{t,p}(\mathbb{S}^1)\hookrightarrow H^{s,p}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is compact for $t>s$ in   M. Pirhayati, “Spectral Theory of Pseudo-Differential Operators on $\mathbb{S}^1$”
